# How to use ArrayList's get() method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to java (& to OOP too) and I'm trying to understand about the class ArrayList
but I don't understand how to use the get(). I tried searching in net, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: What don't you understand about that method exactly?

Comment: i dont understand how to use it

Comment: Object x = myarray.get(1);

Answer (score 21):

Here is the official documentation of [ArrayList.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).

Anyway it is very simple, for example

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
String str = (String) list.get(0); // here you get "1" in str
```

Comment: It is recommended to use Generics though if you're using Java 1.5 or higher.

Answer (score 7):

To put it nice and simply, `get(int index)` returns the element at the specified index.

So say we had an `ArrayList` of `String`s:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Arthur Dent");
names.add("Marvin");
names.add("Trillian");
names.add("Ford Prefect");
```

Which can be visualised as:
[image: A visual representation of the array list]
Where 0, 1, 2, and 3 denote the indexes of the `ArrayList`.

Say we wanted to retrieve one of the names we would do the following:
`String name = names.get(1);`
Which returns the name at the index of 1.

[image: Getting the element at index 1]
So if we were to print out the name `System.out.println(name);` the output would be `Marvin` - Although he might not be too happy with us disturbing him.

Answer (score 4):

You use [`List#get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) to get an object with the index `index` in the list. You use it like that:

```
List<ExampleClass> list = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>();
list.add(new ExampleClass());
list.add(new ExampleClass());
list.add(new ExampleClass());
ExampleClass exampleObj = list.get(2); // will get the 3rd element in the list (index 2);
```

Comment: List<ExampleClass> list = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>();

what is the meaning of using <> thing please?

Comment: This is the generic type of the list, take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 3):

ArrayList `get(int index)` method is used for fetching an element from the list. We need to specify the index while calling get method and it returns the value present at the specified index.

```
public Element get(int index)
```

**Example** : 
In below example we are getting few elements of an arraylist by using get method.

```
package beginnersbook.com;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GetMethodExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
       al.add("pen");
       al.add("pencil");
       al.add("ink");
       al.add("notebook");
       al.add("book");
       al.add("books");
       al.add("paper");
       al.add("white board");

       System.out.println("First element of the ArrayList: "+al.get(0));
       System.out.println("Third element of the ArrayList: "+al.get(2));
       System.out.println("Sixth element of the ArrayList: "+al.get(5));
       System.out.println("Fourth element of the ArrayList: "+al.get(3));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
First element of the ArrayList: pen
Third element of the ArrayList: ink
Sixth element of the ArrayList: books
Fourth element of the ArrayList: notebook
```

Comment: Well written 1st answer! welcome to StackOverflow buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

Would this help?

```
final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) l.add("Number " + i);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) System.out.println(l.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

The get() method returns an element. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
name.add("katy");
name.add("chloe");
System.out.println("The first name in the list is " + name.get(0));
System.out.println("The second name in the list is " + name.get(1));
```

The output:

The first name in the list is katy
The second name in the list is chloe