# Trying to get method inside ArrayList of Objects JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList of objects and i am trying to call a method inside the ArrayList which would return the value of a string. Using a normal Array i can do this but not sure how to do this using an ArrayList, Below is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Animal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       dog d = new dog("Ralph");
       AnimalList dogie = new AnimalList(d);
       ArrayList dogName = dogie.getAnimalList();


       for(int i=0; i<dogName.size();i++){
           System.out.println(dogName.get(i));
       }
    }
```

The class that holds the method is as follows:

```
public class dog extends Animal{
   String dogName;
    public dog(String dogName)
    {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return dogName;
    }
}
```

I
So  am trying to using the getName() method to return the string at the index of the for loop, which then I can using in a System.print. I tryed to get .get(i) followed by the method name but it would not work.

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried `get();`?

Comment: @BitNinja I tryed this, dogName.get(i).getName(); it said it could not find the symbol.

Comment: That's because you used `ArrayList dogeName = dogie.getAnimalList()` instead of `List<Animal> dogeName = dogie.getAnimalList()` so you can access the objects stored inside the List only as an Object but not as an Animal.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259599/how-to-use-arraylists-get-method

Comment: @yossico: That is a not a great link, the top answer doesn't even use generics.

Comment: It is better to rename the class from `dog` to `Dog` to follow the standard naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a new `List` class. Just specialize `ArrayList` to hold `Animal`s.

```
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, `dogs.get(i)` returns a `Dog`. It has a `getName` method.