# Why is this giving a out of bounds exception?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to trouble shoot this section for a while now and can't seem to understand why this keeps throwing an out of bounds exception. Trouble shooting seems to say that I shouldn't be I shouldn't be going out of bounds however the results produced seem inconsistent. For instance, here is a result from a test. I can't really understand how something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAYOJ.png) would happen. Is there anything obviously wrong with this method for setting neighbors of objects in an ArrayList? I just want to know if there are any glaring logical errors here, if not I will just have to test more on my own. Thank you for the help.

```
    public void setNeighbors(ArrayList<ArrayList<Objects>> arrayList) //sets the neighboring tiles for each tile
{
    //arrayList is an multi dimensional array of Objects with a variable size. It is created in another method
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < arrayList.get(i).size(); x++)
        {
            // 1 2 3 
            // 4 @ 6
            // 7 8 9
            if((i>0&&x>0) && x<arrayList.get(i).size()-1 && i<arrayList.size()-1)
            {   //goes 1 3 7 9
                System.out.println("Max X:"+(arrayList.get(i).size()-1));
                System.out.println("Max Y:"+(arrayList.size()-1));
                System.out.println("X:"+x);
                System.out.println("Y:"+i);
                // A Floor is a type of Object and addNeighbor adds a Floor object to an ArrayList of Floor Objects within a Floor
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x-1));
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x+1));
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x-1));
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x+1));
            }
            if (x>0 && x<arrayList.get(i).size()-1) 
            { // 4 6
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x-1));
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x+1));
            }
            if (i>0 && i<arrayList.size()-1) 
            { // 2 8
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x));
                ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x+1)); here x +1 can be greater than the array

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @juzraai It depends, it seems that any line can, however in the last test it was the last line in first if statement, with the error showcased in the picture.

Comment: @Denis Shouldn't the checks included in the if statements prevent it from going out of bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code seems to be blowing up on the value of x+1, either the line
`((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x+1));`

or the line

`((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x+1));`

are at fault. In either case, it suggests that the individual ArrayLists are not of a constant length.

Comment: This was the answer, thank you. The problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if-statement` you have:

`if((i>0&&x>0) && x<arrayList.get(i).size()-1 && i<arrayList.size()-1)`

So you check to make sure that `x` is in the bounds for the arrayList in the `ith` position. However you change `i`. So while `x` could be in bounds for `arrayList(i)` it might not be in bounds for `arrayList(i + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

When either `i` or `x` are already at their maximum valid values, your code can still try to add 1 to them and use the result for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

the cause are the following lines regarding the x+1 and i+1

```
 ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x+1));
```

Your if clause have to check for size()-2 on the x and i variable not -1.

Without knowing what your are exactly doing this should work. Think the algorithm will not work in the right manner , you have to check

```
for(int x = 0; x < arrayList.get(i).size(); x++)
    {
        // 1 2 3 
        // 4 @ 6
        // 7 8 9
        if((i>0&&x>0) && x<arrayList.get(i).size()-2 && i<arrayList.size()-2)
        {   //goes 1 3 7 9
            System.out.println("Max X:"+(arrayList.get(i).size()-1));
            System.out.println("Max Y:"+(arrayList.size()-1));
            System.out.println("X:"+x);
            System.out.println("Y:"+i);
            // A Floor is a type of Object and addNeighbor adds a Floor object to an ArrayList of Floor Objects within a Floor
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x-1));
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x+1));
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x-1));
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x+1));
        }
        if (x>0 && x<arrayList.get(i).size()-2) 
        { // 4 6
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x-1));
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x+1));
        }
        if (i>0 && i<arrayList.size()-2) 
        { // 2 8
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i-1).get(x));
            ((Floor)arrayList.get(i).get(x)).addNeighbor((Floor)arrayList.get(i+1).get(x));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Since the OP has it less than the size -1, adding one to the index will not cause it to go out of bounds

Comment: Yeah but size gives you the length of an Arraylist so List with four elements has size four , but your index  i or x starts at 0.

Comment: But the `i` and `x` will only loop until *less* than the size minus one (Two in our example of the size being four) so when you add one you will get three, which is a valid index in our imaginary `ArrayList`

Comment: But this is wrong. Example your list has 3 elements. the last element of the list is addressed by get(2). 
So if your if clause goes size() -1 (3-1) = 2 , and then you try to get(2+1) this cause index out of bounds , because your last element is get(2) and not get(3). Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259599/how-to-use-arraylists-get-method

Comment: No in the example it had four elements. So get(3) will be the last index of the `ArrayList`

Comment: `ArrayList.size() == 4`. `ArrayList.size -1 == 3`. `x` looping while it is less than `ArrayList.size-1` (3), will only allow it to go to 2. Then when you add one you'll be calling `get(3)`, which is a valid index when the `ArrayList` has four elements